# ASP.NET Core Identity - Username already exists when Updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm just trying to Update an already existing user using Asp Core Identity with a custom UserStore.

Some code context :

**(Custom ApplicationUser)**

```
public class ApplicationUser {
    public string web_user_soc_code { get; set; }
    public string web_user_id { get; set; }
    public string web_user_name { get; set; }
    public string web_user_normalized_name { get; set; }
    public string web_user_password { get; set; }
    public DateTime? web_user_date_crea { get; set; }
    public List<ApplicationRole> roles { get; set; }
}
```

**(Custom UserStore)**

[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/S8DpB8Kb)

**(Update method in my Controller)**

```
[HttpPut]
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrateur")]
public JsonResult UpdateUser(string id, string username) {
    ApplicationUser user = userManager.FindByIdAsync(id).Result;
    if (user == null || user.web_user_id == null) {
        return Json(new { success = false, responseText = "Imposible de trouver l'utilisateur demandé" });
    }

    // Replacing with the new username
    user.web_user_name = username;

    // Updating... Throws error "Username xxx already exists"
    IdentityResult result = userManager.UpdateAsync(user).Result;
    return Json(result == IdentityResult.Success ?
        new { success = true, responseText = "L'utilisateur a été modifié avec succès" } :
        new { success = false, responseText = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault()?.Description });
}
```

So all I want to achieve is to update his username, but when I call the `userManager.UpdateAsync(user)`, I have an error saying that this username already exists (of course it doesn't)...
I've seen that the same error is thrown when I use `userManager.SetUserNameAsync(...)`.

So I have absolutely no idea where it could come from / what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you using a custom implementation of `IUserValidator`?

Comment: No, I'm using the default one @KirkLarkin

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserValidator.cs#L76) the code that's responsible for reporting that error. You might be able to backtrace from there to see what's going wrong for your setup.

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much! My `FindUserByNameAsync` method was returning an empty User instead of `null` if nothing was found... And since IUserValidator only checks for null values, it wasn't working correctly.